# create a toggle menu in form of vertical list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a toggle menu, i have a menu that expands when i click on it and closes when i click on it again.

HTML code for it is

```
<label for="menu-toggle"><img src="icons/navicon.png"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"/>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
    </ul>
```

css is

```
<style>
label
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
#menu-toggle 
    {
        display: none; /* hide the checkbox */
    }
#menu 
    {
        display: none;
    }
#menu-toggle:checked + #menu 
    {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

the toggle looks like this

[image]

when i click on the 3 lines image it looks like this

[image]

I want  that when i click on the 3 lines image, the menu should get displayed in a vertical list, within a block with white background . something like this

[image]

can anyone tell me how i can do so

Comment: you want css toggle menu ?

Answer (score 0):

the images are not visible here. but what you can do is css for background color and width tag for a block.

something like

`#menu
    {
        display: none;
        width: 30%;
     background-color:green;`

Answer (score 0):

Update following CSS:

```
#menu {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#menu-toggle:checked + #menu {
    display: block;
}

li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;   
}

#menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;    
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ss3zent/)

Comment: @lyra, Adjust width and color schemes as per your requirement.

Comment: the menu is still getting aligned in  horizontal list, and the img also moves to left,

Comment: Have you seen my DEMO? There must be other CSS which is conflicting on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just did some adjustments to your given code, and hope the output is close to the one in your given picture.

```css
<style>
label
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9A9494;
   }

 li { 
   border-bottom:#ccc solid 1px; /* This is the divider line in between the list items */    
    }

#menu-toggle
    {
        display: none; /* hide the checkbox */
    }

#menu 
    {
        display: none;             
    }

#menu-toggle:checked + #menu 
    {
        display: block;
    }

 .xyz{
  
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;  
   }
   
 .container{
  background-color: #ccc;
  width:15%;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }  

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>DropDown</title> 
</head>
<body>

<label for="menu-toggle"><img src="icons/navicon.png"></label>
<div class="container">
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"/>
   
    <ul id="menu" style="list-style: none; padding:15px; border-radius: 15px;" >
    
        <li class="xyz" ><a href="#" >First link</a></li>  
        <li class="xyz"><a href="#">Second link</a></li> 
        <li class="xyz"><a href="#">Third link</a></li>

    </ul>
   
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

I combined stylesheet with the html... Nice helping you.. :)

Comment: View the answer in full screen, coz the widths i specified are in "%" , so it is according to full screen width, you can change it accordingly..